# Identify diode SNFEIB

Tags: diodes, identification

I need a 12V 2A flyback diode for a solenoid and salvaged this unknown diode from a *TR101 E-Panel* (D5).
The markings on the diode are **SN FE IB** and a curvy U shape logo. 6.2mm long and 3.2mm diameter.
[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

[image: pic3]

What are the specs of this diode and is it enough to use as a 2A flyback diode?

Comment: Just buy a proper diode and be done.

Comment: That might be a TVS diode

Comment: A zener makes the solenoid release faster but voltage depends on supply and too much action makes it burn out